# How to get that Apollo Client is refetching specific query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

There are several places in the app where specific query is refetched after different mutations.

Example:

```
// Some component
const [setUserLocation, setUserLocationResult] = useMutation(setUserLocationMutation, {
  refetchQueries: [{ query: getRecommendationsQuery }],
});
```

And in my `RecommendationsComponent` I want to know that this query is loading, but `useQuery`'s `loading` doesn't update when `getRecommendationsQuery` is refetched.

```
const {
  data,
  loading, // this loading is false all the time except first loading
} = useQuery(getRecommendationsQuery);
```

I can try put `useQuery`'s `refetch` to the context and use it everywhere rather than `refetchQueries` prop, but is there a better way to achieve that without that dirty hack - either make `loading` work or subscribe to that info using apollo client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two [answers](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/8888) in github for that question, combined them both and it finally worked:

Pass `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` to `useQuery`:

```
const { data, loading } = useQuery(getRecommendationsQuery, {
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
});
```

Pass documents, not objects to refetchQueries prop:

```
// Some component
const [setUserLocation, setUserLocationResult] = useMutation(setUserLocationMutation, {
  refetchQueries: [getRecommendationsQuery],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

useQuery Hook will call the api only once. You need to call the `refetch` function to call it again

```
const {
  data,
  loading, 
  refetch: getRecommendations // <- use this function to refetch the data
} = useQuery(getRecommendationsQuery);
```

This will also update the `loading` state

Comment: At least in Apollo 3.6.3 that is not the case and refetching does not upload the loading state.

Answer (score -1):

When the query is refetched, the data will be updated. You can subscribe to changes in the `data` object returned from the `useQuery` hook:

```
const {
  data,
  loading,
} = useQuery(getRecommendationsQuery);

useEffect(() => {
  console.debug("data has changed!", data]);
}, [data]);
```

Comment: I need to know when it is refetching - its loading state, not when it was refetched.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov then set a state `isRefetching` as true immediately after submitting your mutation and in the useEffect above set it as false when it has completed refetching.

Comment: I got mutations all over my code, in lots of components.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import { NetworkStatus, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

...

const { data, networkStatus, error } = useQuery(QUERY_DOC);

...

const isRefetching = networkStatus === NetworkStatus.refetch;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).